# Performing a JSON operation on dataframe column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, where one of the columns is a column of strings, which can be converted by separately with `json.loads(string)` to a dictionary.

I'd like to perform `json.loads()` on the entire column at once, turning the **column of strings**, to a **column of dictionaries**.

Is this possible?

Comment: `df['my_col_name'].apply(json.loads)`

Comment: Do you think `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) or `list comprehension`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)

df['col'] = [pd.io.json.loads(x) for x in df['col']]
```

Another more general solution:

```
import ast
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```